# how to include and add meta tags php script

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Including and adding meta tags to this script for social media sharing. where are the meta data included?

```
<?php 


validate_get($_GET['article']);
$id=$_GET['article'];

$title='';


include("includes/header.php");


?>

<div id="content">

    <div>
        <?php
            $query="SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ARTICLE_ID = {$id} ";
            $article_set =  get_result_set($query);
            if(mysql_num_rows($article_set)==0)
                redirect_to("blog.php");
            else{
                $article=mysql_fetch_array ($article_set);

                echo "
                    <div id='container-left2'>
                        <div><h2>{$article['ARTICLE_TITLE']}</h2></div>

                        <div id='article-date'>
                        <div class='month'>" . datetime_month($article['TIMESTAMP'])."</div><br>
                            <div class='date'>" . datetime_date($article['TIMESTAMP'])."</div><br>
                            <div class='year'>" . datetime_year($article['TIMESTAMP'])."</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id='article-content'>
                            <div id='by'>
                                <span class='article-author'>POSTED BY <a href='#'>Administrator</a> </span>
                                <span>ON ". datetime_to_text($article['TIMESTAMP']). "</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>{$article['ARTICLE_CONTENT']}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clear:both;'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id='container-right'></div>
                    <div class='clear:both;'></div>
                ";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class='clear:both;'></div>

<div>


<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
```

Wanted to include links with the article titles and images for social media
they end up having no title and image.
This are the meta tags to use where?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The best site">
<meta property="og:image" content="link_to_image">
<meta property="og:description" content="description goes here">
```

Comment: It's used for FaceBook

Comment: @Jack,yes good to know, i want to include them on the script posted above

Comment: Add your meta in the `<head></head>`. Here you put **meta**, link to .css and title

Comment: @Dimitri Mockelyn Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Hearner this script wysiwyg, where the meta tags go with no <head></head>